# C argument of type * is incompatible with parameter of type *

Tags: c, stm32, hid, keil, stm32f1

I'm trying to make HID on STM32 board. But i stuck with next problem: I don't understand where my mistake, i passing a pointer to struct which contains data for report function, but when i try to compile code i get next messsage: argument of type "keyboardHID *" is incompatible with parametr of type "uint8_t *" I write code in the same way like man from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tj1_hsQ5PR0. In his case, this is not a critical error and code compiles.

My struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t MODIFIER;
    uint8_t RESERVED;
    uint8_t KEYCODE1;
    uint8_t KEYCODE2;
    uint8_t KEYCODE3;
    uint8_t KEYCODE4;
    uint8_t KEYCODE5;
    uint8_t KEYCODE6;
} keyboardHID;

keyboardHID keyboardhid = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // it should be like this, not differently
```

Code that modifies structure elements and sends reports to the computer:

```
keyboardhid.MODIFIER = 0x02;  // left Shift
        keyboardhid.KEYCODE1 = 0x04;  // press 'a'
        keyboardhid.KEYCODE2 = 0x05;  // press 'b'
        USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &keyboardhid, sizeof (keyboardhid));
        HAL_Delay (50);
        
        keyboardhid.MODIFIER = 0x00;  // shift release
        keyboardhid.KEYCODE1 = 0x00;  // release key
        keyboardhid.KEYCODE2 = 0x00;  // release key
        USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, &keyboardhid, sizeof (keyboardhid));
        HAL_Delay (1000);
```

Comment: The message is clear. You're using a `keyboardhid *` in a place where a `uint8_t *` is expected. Your compiler is helpful and issues a diagnostic. **IF YOU ARE CERTAIN IT'S OK** you can try a cast `USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS, (uint8_t*)&keyboardhid, sizeof (keyboardhid));`... but don't tell anybody I even suggested this. Again, for extra emphasis: **ONLY DO THIS IF YOU'RE CERTAIN IT'S OK**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works and that's enough for me

Comment: A man who teaches programming in a video is not to be taken seriously.

Answer (score 1):

C allows implicit pointer conversions only to `void*`.
Types `uint8_t` and `keyboardHID` are not compatible, neither their pointer.
I assume that `uint8_t` is `unsigned char` but C standard does not require it.

Usually, functions that process memory directly should use `void*` like `memcpy()` or `memset()` but it looks that `USBD_HID_SendReport()` is not following this convention.

You can:

1. Cast `&keyboardhid` to `uint8_t*`. It's safe because character types have the least alignment requirements. Moreover, characters are an explicit exception to strict aliasing rules.
2. Use `&keyboardhid.MODIFIER`. C standard requires the address of the structure to be the same as an address of its first element. IMO, it is the most obscure way.
3. Use an union.

```
union {
  keyboardHID keyboardhid;
  uint8_t bytes[sizeof(keyboardHID)];
} u;
```

And pass `u.bytes` to `USBD_HID_SendReport()`.

I would go for option 1 as it is the simplest and safe. Option 3 will be the best if `keyboardhid` had to be cast to something other than `void*` or a pointer to character type (i.e. `uint32_t*`).